# TypeScript error when using this type as a generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, this

When I use the following code, I get the error described in the comment.
What am I missing here?

```
type MyEvent<S extends Bindable> = {
    source: S;
};

type MyListener<S extends Bindable> =
    (event: MyEvent<S>) => void;

interface Bindable {
    listener: MyListener<this>;
};

interface Row extends Bindable {
    id: number;
}

declare var e: MyEvent<Row>;
//                     ^
// Type 'Row' does not satisfy the constraint 'Bindable'.
//   Types of property 'listener' are incompatible.
//     Type 'MyListener<Row>' is not assignable to type 'MyListener<Bindable>'.
//       Property 'id' is missing in type 'Bindable' but required in type 'Row'.ts(2344)
```

Comment: Which Typescript version are you using?

Comment: I'm using typescript 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to Bindable whereas you want it to refer to `Row`. Do this instead:

```
type MyEvent<S extends Bindable<S>> = {
    source: S;
}

type MyListener<S extends Bindable<S>> = (event: MyEvent<S>) => void;

interface Bindable<Self extends Bindable<Self>> {
    listener: MyListener<Self>;
}

interface Row extends Bindable<Row> {
    id: number;
}

declare var e: MyEvent<Row>;
```

**Edit:** or one small change might be better for your use case:

```
interface Bindable {
    listener: MyListener<Bindable>;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid by using 'this'. But the problem is at the function signature of MyListener. If I change the type of listener property to MyEvent<this> (which of course is not what I'm trying to do), it does not complain

Answer (score 0):

I understand my problem now.
The thing is that the following code would break the constraint.

```
interface Unrelated extends Bindable {
   prop: number;
}

var bindable: Bindable;
declare var row: Row;
declare var listener: MyListener<Unrelated>;
bindable = row;
bindable.listener = listener;
```

because a `MyListener<Unrelated>` value
would be assigned to a `MyListener<Row>` property.

In fact, after further testing, I discovered that the following code:

```
interface A {
    prop: (parm: this) => void;
}

interface B extends A {
    propB: number;
}

interface C extends A {
    propC: number;
}

declare var b: B;
declare var c: C;
var a: A;
a = b;
```

has the same issue, but if I change `interface A` to:

```
interface A {
   prop: this
}
```

it is not, which should issue the same error because I could assign a C value to B's prop which has a B type through variable a.